# this.props.function name is not defined

Tags: reactjs, redux

Hey all I am working with creating a redux application however within one of my components I have a method I created that is accessing its actioncreator method however when accessing it the console is saying it is this.props.selectBook is not a function. I have no idea what is happening or would it could be.

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {selectBook} from '../actions/index';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';

class BookList extends React.Component {
    renderList() {
        return this.props.books.map((book) => {
            return (
            <li onClick={() => this.props.selectBook(book)} key={book.title} className="list-group-item">{book.title}</li>
            );
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ul className="list-group col-sm-4">
                {this.renderList()}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        books: state.books
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({selectBook: selectBook}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BookList);
```

~ action creator

```
 export default function selectBook (book) {
    return {
        type: 'BOOK_SELECTED',
        payload: book
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that inside your `actions/index` file you exported selectBook with default keyword which means in your component you have to import selectBook by this syntax

`import selectBook from '../actions/index';`

Right now you have imported the selectBook with this syntax

`import {selectBook} from '../actions/index';`

Hence selectBook is undefined.

If you want to use this syntax in your file you have to export selectBook normally like this

```
export function selectBook (book) {
   return {
       type: 'BOOK_SELECTED',
       payload: book
   }
}
```